# JavaScript throws: "is not a function" when I pass object as argument

Tags: javascript

This is my simple code:

```
var x = 0, y = 0;

function start() {
    var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas"), ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

    animate(ctx);
}

function animate(ctx) {
    ctx.clearRect(0,0,500,500);
    ctx.fillRect(x, y, 20, 20);
    ctx.save();
    x++;
    window.requestAnimationFrame(animate);
}
```

When I run this code a error occurs "ctx.clearRect is not a function" but when I get context from canvas in method animate instead of pass it as argument it's working.

Comment: the `ctx` parameter of the `animate` function will not be available when called by `requestAnimationFrame `

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have to pass the `ctx` context on the next tick, otherwise the `ctx` argument is `undefined`, and `undefined` has no method `clearRect`

```
function animate(ctx) {
    ctx.clearRect(0,0,500,500);
    ctx.fillRect(x, y, 20, 20);
    ctx.save();
    x++;
    window.requestAnimationFrame(function() {
        animate(ctx);
    });
}
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/d0bt2bz9/)

Comment: Alternately: `window.requestAnimationFrame(animate.bind(null, ctx));`